# Flutter Bad state: Future already completed. Error thrown by an image listener

Tags: flutter, dart

I sometime got the following error in my `Crashlytics`:

> Bad state: Future already completed. Error thrown by an image listener.

This is my function to calculate an image dimension, where I think the **error** is thrown:

```
Future<Size> calculateImageDimension(
    String imageUrl, BuildContext context) async {
  Completer<Size> completer = Completer();
  late Image image;
  image = Image.network(
    imageUrl,
  );

  if (!await hasValidImageData(imageUrl, context)) {
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print('invaaaaliiiiiiiiiiiiiiddddd');
    return Future.value(const Size(0, 0));
  }

  image.image.resolve(const ImageConfiguration()).addListener(
    ImageStreamListener(
      (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
        var myImage = image.image;
        Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
        if (!completer.isCompleted) {
          completer.complete(size);
        }
      },
    ),
  );

  return completer.future;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I couldn't reproduce the error on my side... Let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just a random thought, have you tried to replace

```dart
return Future.value(const Size(0, 0));
```

with something like

```dart
Completer.complete(const Size(0, 0));
return completer.future;
```

My guess is that at some point (at the start probably), there's no valid image data and thus it returns a completed `Future`. Another option is that there's a race condition somewhere but without more information it'd be hard to point you towards the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Future` is trying to completed more than once. I mean the `Future` returning by your `calculateImageDimension` is trying to  return and complete again and again so that's probably create the error.

After checking your code, I see here that `Future` is inside your callback(`ImageStreamListener`) and called every time if the image is being loaded from the network and/or the network conditions change until the image is resolve.

So, let me change the structure of your code like below;

```
Future<Size> calculateImageDimension(String imageUrl, BuildContext context) async {
 Completer<Size> completer = Completer();
 ImageProvider imageProvider = NetworkImage(imageUrl);

 if (!await hasValidImageData(imageUrl, context)) {
   print('invaaaaliiiiiiiiiiiiiiddddd');
   return Future.value(const Size(0, 0));
 }

 ImageStream stream = imageProvider.resolve(const ImageConfiguration());
 ImageStreamListener listener = ImageStreamListener(
   (ImageInfo image, bool synchronousCall) {
     var myImage = image.image;
     Size size = Size(myImage.width.toDouble(), myImage.height.toDouble());
     if (!completer.isCompleted) {
       completer.complete(size);
     }
   },
 );

 stream.addListener(listener);

 return completer.future;
```

See that the `ImageStreamListener` is added to the `ImageStream` returned by the resolve method of the `ImageProvider`. This because we need to ensure that your `Future` is only completed once when the image is loaded for the first time. For this, even if the image will loaded multiple times, it will not affect the `Future` and not be completed again. This approach hopingly to prevent error(*Bad state: Future already completed.*)

Lastly, when your done, do call `removeListener` method on the `ImageStream` to remove the listener by a `stream.removeListener(listener);`. This should be done in the `dispose` method of your widget, or wherever you're done with the `Future` returned by `calculateImageDimension`.

This seems to be unnecessary, but we use it to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: this looks really promising and well explained, thank you! One question: Where should I remove the listener? the stream only exists inside the function, or am I missing something?